# Beamer uncover takes additional step to perform

Tags: beamer, uncover

```
\documentclass[aspectratio=169]{beamer}
\usepackage{transparent}

\setbeamercovered{transparent}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{Frame Title}
 \begin{itemize}[<+- |uncover@+>]
   \item item 1
   \item<4> \alert{item 2}
   \item<4> \alert{item 3}
   \item item 4
 \end{itemize}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

To display `item 2 & 3` on the 4th slide takes additional key press.

Comment: Well, that does make a lot of sense actually. Your global `uncover` uncovers item 1 on slide 1, item 4 on slide 2, per definition nothing on slide 3 and then items 2 and 3 on slide 4. To change that simply use `<3>` instead of `<4>` and you're good to go.

Comment: After seeing your comment I realised now that a slide is missing. Thanks a lot!